# Screen captures of windows larger than screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen-capture

Is there a way to capture a screenshot of a browser window / webpage which is larger than the MacBook Air (1366x768) screen it's displayed on?

I need to have captures of how a site displays in a 1280x1024 window. I can use [Moom](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12&uo=4&at=11l9kI) to resize the browser window, but not sure how to get the snap.

Comment: Pressing ⌘⇧4, then space, then clicking the window only enables you to capture the visible parts on the screen. To capture a whole webpage, you can use Snagit, or some web-based applications like [Site2pic](http://www.site2pic.com/) and [Webpage Screenshot Capture](http://screenshot.net/webpage-screenshot). All these tools allow you to screenshot an entire webpage just with its URL.

Comment: True for both — I use a Chrome extension to do that sort of thing — but I was looking for the browser window, and not just the webpage. My question was a bit unclear. I do appreciate your chiming in though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take screenshots of entire windows, even those that extend beyond the bounds of the screen, by **pressing ⌘⇧4, then space, then clicking the window**.

Comment: Hmm. In my case, it just gave me a shot of the window that was visible on screen but I'm looking for a slightly different use case.